# how to replace IP address on remote host using expect

Tags: linux, shell-script, perl, ksh, expect

I wrote the following `expect` script in order to replace the IP address on remote Linux machine

I use a `perl` one-liner for this task

I get errors about can't read "HOME": no such variable ,

Please advise on what I need to change in my `expect` script so I can change the requested IP ?

```
 #!/bin/ksh


 expect_transfer=`cat << EOF
 set timeout -1
 spawn  ssh  12.219.102.43
       expect {
                 ")?"   { send "yes\r"  ; exp_continue  }

                 word:  {send pass123\r}
              }
  expect #  {send "export OLD=10.10.10.10 ; export NEW=1.1.1.1 ; perl -i -pe 's/\Q$ENV{OLD}\E/$1$ENV{NEW}$2/' /etc/hosts\r"}
  expect #    {send exit\r}
  expect eof
  EOF`


  expect -c  "$expect_transfer"
```

results:

```
  spawn ssh 12.219.102.43
  root@12.219.102.43's password: 
  Last login: Sun Aug  4 12:29:25 2013 from 12.219.102.43
  [root@localhost ~]# can't read "HOME": no such variable
  while executing
   "send "export OLD=10.10.10.10 ; export NEW=1.1.1.1 ; perl -i -pe 's/\Q$HOME/.kshrc{OLD}\E/$HOME/.kshrc{NEW}/' /etc/hosts\r""
  invoked from within
  "expect #  {send "export OLD=10.10.10.10 ; export NEW=1.1.1.1 ; perl -i -pe 's/\Q$HOME/.kshrc{OLD}\E/$HOME/.kshrc{NEW}/' /etc/hosts"
```

- I will happy to get any other solution under ksh scripts

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `$ENV` is expanded to `$HOME/.kshrc` in

`send "export OLD=10.10.10.10 ; export NEW=1.1.1.1 ; perl -i -pe 's/\Q$HOME/.kshrc{OLD}\E/$HOME/.kshrc{NEW}/' /etc/hosts\r`

You could

1. try $OLD and $NEW in the Perl line,
2. ditch expect in favor of plain ssh: `ssh root@12.219.102.43 -- sed -i s/$OLD/$NEW/ /etc/hosts`

   With a proper keys setup, you don't need a password either.